# Add collision to only the borders of a node, allowing a sprite to move freely inside of the node

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I am building a game in which I "dig" underground to allow a ball to fall through. Is it possible to allow this ball collide with the borders of the node whilst inside of it. Based on the image below, my goal is to draw a tunnel with touchMoved and let the ball fall in while colliding with the surface of the tunnel.

[image: Example of goal]

Comment: physics body from the outer shapes of the tunnel?

Comment: @Fluidity Yes, the edges of the white space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should should use the 2 sides of the tunnel to define SKShapeNodes so that when the ball is in the tunnel, it *isn't* inside a node.

In your example picture, you would have 2 nodes - one for each of the black areas.

Then set up your collision parameters such that the ball cannot pass through the shapes

Comment: I tried that but it was extremely jittery and the ball often got stuck.

Comment: If the path the defines the tunnel’s edge isn’t smooth, then I can see that happening.  You’d probable want a smooth curve that approximates to the rough texture.

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways to achieve the same thing in spriteKit.

```
// add your rectangle size for example 
SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: scene.frame)
```

but in your case as it's in the image. You have to draw the tunnel you can draw your physics body using the points and give it a **physicsBody** and then set the isDynamic to false which means the body will not be moved by other physic bodies. You can still move it using actions which is called **kinematic**.

```
// After you draw your physicsBody set the isDynamic physicsBody property to false
tunnel.physicsBody.isDynamic = false
```

Now the body will collide with other physic bodies but will not be affected by any kind of collision or gravity

Comment: I created a constant: let edge = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: tunnel.frame) which was given to each instance of the tunnel, yet it still just falls through the tunnel

Comment: Falls thorough eh tunnel into the ground? Can you post your code where you set up the collision parameters - collisionBitMasks, categoryBitMasks etc.